# Platform Data Extension: how do I parse ROAD_NAME_FCN

Tags: here-api

I'm using HERE's Platform Data Extension to retrieve road names. However, I don't understand the strings that I'm getting. I suspect they're encoded somehow but I don't know how to decode them.

For example:

```
ENGBNFDR Dr NNASN"e|fe "de "e|rre "dri|ve "nol|te;NASY"e|fe "de "e|rre;<snip>
```

If I split them by a "record separator" character, e.g. `link_names.split('\x1e')` the values look slightly more intelligible, but only slightly. There are still bizarre abbreviations I don't understand, e.g. `ENGBN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDE Layers documents can be found here: http://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/doc/content.html?detail=1&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy

> Layers > ROAD_NAME_FC1 > NAMES.

List of all names for this object, in all languages, latin1/pinyin/phonetic transliterations.
For convenience, non-exonym base names are listed first.

Format:

```
NAMES = NAME1 \u001D NAME2 \u001D NAME3 ... 
NAME = NAME_TEXT \u001E TRANSLIT1 ; TRANSLIT2 ; ... \u001E PHONEME1 ; PHONEME2 ; ... NAME_TEXT = LANGUAGE_CODE NAME_TYPE IS_EXONYM text 
TRANSLIT = LANGUAGE_CODE text 
PHONEME = LANGUAGE_CODE IS_PREFERRED text 
LANGUAGE_CODE is a 3 character string 
NAME_TYPE is one letter (A = abbreviation, B = base name, E = exonym, K = shortened name, S = synonym) 
IS_EXONYM = Y if the name is a translation into another language 
IS_PREFERRED = Y if this is the preferred phoneme. 

Please note, the delimiters are: 
\u001D between languages (NAMES level) 
\u001E between name text, transliterations, and phonemes ';' between different transliterations and phonemes of the same name.
```